# A question about a Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I encountered a question about Markov Chains which looks interesting.

Given a homogeneous, irreducible, non cyclic Markov Chain with $K$ possible states and a transition matrix $Q$.

We define $T_i$ to be a random variable which is the minimal time ($t\geq1$) in which the Chain reaches a state $i$.

We also define a $K\times K$ matrix $M$ as follows: $M_{ij}=E[T_j|X(0)=i]$.

We define $C$ as a matrix of ones, and $D$ a diagonal matrix: $D_{ii}=M_{ii}$.

Prove that $M=C+Q(M-D)$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to start solving this? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Hint: Markov property after one step.

Comment: Uhm, still nothing. Maybe a bigger hint, if you could?

Comment: What did you try to use the hint?

Comment: I don't really understand how to do so.

Comment: Which similar questions can you solve? (You realize that, until now, you gave us *nothing* except the flat statement of your problem?)

Comment: I can solve simple questions about Markov Chains. And I apologize for giving only the the statement of the problem, but that's only because I don't even know where to begin as I've said. It's not homework or anything like that, I'm just trying to figure out how to solve questions like this one.
I'm not asking for a full solution of the problem (although that would be nice), but for a helpful hint for a beginner in these types of questions. I can't even see why $M=C+Q(M-D)$ makes sense, so it's difficult for me to try and prove it.